# Float is breaking link on website

Tags: html, css

I have a div on my website in which has span classes encased. One of these is meant to have a mailto: link, however, it seems that because the div is floated right, the link does not work. If i remove the float, everything works as it should.

HTML:

```
<div class="topMenu">
 <div class="contactInfo">
  <span class="topMenuSpan">call us:</span><span class="topMenuInfo"> 01892   704 201</span> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
 <span class="topMenuSpan"><a href="http://www.google.com">email us:</a></span>
 <span class="topMenuInfo">info@doyouknowbonobo.co.uk</span></div></a>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.topMenu{
height:36px;
background:#000;
font-family: adelle-sans;
font-weight:600;
font-size:15px;
color:#fff;
text-align:right;
float:right;
position:relative;
right:5.7%;
width:612px;
}

.topMenuSpan{
color:#ffdc31;
cursor:pointer;
}

.topMenuInfo{
color:#fff;
cursor:pointer;
}

.topMenu .contactInfo{
cursor:pointer;
position:relative;
right: 15%;
top: 5px;
}

.topMenuSpan:hover{
color:#fff;
-o-transition:.5s;
-ms-transition:.5s;
-moz-transition:.5s;
-webkit-transition:.5s;
transition:.5s;
cursor:pointer;
}

.topMenuInfo:hover{
color:#ffdc33;
-o-transition:.5s;
-ms-transition:.5s;
-moz-transition:.5s;
-webkit-transition:.5s;
transition:.5s;
}
```

Link to website: http://scottadmin.co.uk/monkey/

How do i stop the float breaking the link?

Comment: in your style.css file search "nav .container" on line no. 143 and change padding-top: 67px; to margin-top: 67px;

Answer (score 2):

The Link isn't broken - it's merely not in the foreground. Try adding:

```
.topMenu{
z-index:100;
}
```

Comment: You might want to give it a unique ID though, instead of JUST a class